# drush orphaned actions drupal error

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drush

when i run drush sometimes i get: "2 orphaned actions (comment_publish_action, comment_unpublish_action) exist in the actions[warning] table. Remove orphaned actions"
or somthing like that, is that critial error? or i should ignore it? what is that means? and how to solve it?

Comment: if you add -d or --debug in the option you will get the full details of what is happening as drush runs and this can be useful iin, well debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's in the console, you don't see the link. But the "Remove orphaned actions" text is a link to **admin/config/system/actions/orphan** which then fixes the problem.

An *orphaned action* is an action that exist in the database but is no longer found in the code (for example, because the module that provides them has been disabled).

Comment: The path (link) mentioned by coracho is for Drupal 7. For Drupal 6 the path is **admin/settings/actions/orphan**

When you visit this page it removes the orphaned actions and then redirects you to the Manage Actions page.

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
drush php-eval "actions_synchronize(TRUE);" -l site.com
```

There is no `admin/config/system/actions/orphan` page at my Drupal 7. It just redirects  to the normal actions page.

Also see [actions_synchronize()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!actions.inc/function/actions_synchronize/7) for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

Using drush on commandline for clearing orphaned actions:

- drupal 7: `drush php-eval "actions_synchronize(TRUE);"`
- drupal 6: `drush php-eval "actions_synchronize(actions_list(), TRUE);"`